Jetpack Compose: how to read the contents of a text file into an app program
I’m trying to learn Jetpack Compose with Android Studio.  I want to create an app for an android tablet.  I need  the app to read a string from a local file held on the app, but I can’t get anything to work.
For example, I have a data file installed in app->res->xml called testfile.xml.  (testfile.xml does contain XML type of data, but that is not important for my app.  If using XML here is a problem, I could just as well use some other format, because it’s just for my own use in the app.  I just need to read a file containing a long string.)
Following a suggestion in Stack Overflow, I’ve tried several approaches, such as
text = stringResource(R.res.testfile)
When I run this, the program doesn’t crash, but I find that “text” just contains the string “res/xml/testname.xml”, not the contents of testfile.xml.
I’ve also tried:
InputStream iS = resources.getAssets().open(R.xml.testfile)
var text = File("testfile.xml").readText()
var text = File(“path/testfile.xml”).readText()
These all just crash.
Obviously I’m just doing something stupid, but I can’t find a way to get the text from a text file into the program.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Many thanks.
